# Operator overload syntax clarification

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Can someone please explain how the following syntax differences change the way the operator works?

```
T & operator()(type one, type two)
const T * operator()(type one, type two)
T & operator()(type one) const
const T & operator()(type one) const
```

Comment: Helpful Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 5):

Assuming they are all members, all of them take a `type` objects by value. That means that, at least semantically, the body operator has its own copy of the `type` objects. The `operator()` syntax means that instances are callable. What follows after `operator()`, e.g. `(type a, type b)`, is the parameter list.

This one takes two `type`s`type`, and returns a reference to `T`. Cannot be used on `const` instance.

```
T & operator()(type one, type two)
```

It could be called something like this:

```
MyFunctor x;
type a, b;
T& r = x(a,b); // take reference
T c = x(a,b);  // make copy from reference. Assumes T has copy constructor
```

This version takes two `type`s, and returns a pointer to `const T`. Cannot be used on `const` instance. No non-const methods of `T` can be called.

```
const T * operator()(type one, type two)
```

Example:

```
MyFunctor x;
type a, b;
const T* p1 = x(a,b); // pointer to const
T* p2 = x(a,b);       // Error! Must have const T* on LHS
```

This one takes a single `type`, and returns a reference to `T`. Can be used on all instances, const or non-const. Depending on what the returned reference refers to, it may break `const` consistency in allowing you to modify internal data via a const method:

```
T & operator()(type one) const
```

The last one works as the one above, except that no non `const` methods of whatever the return refers to can be called.

```
const T & operator()(type one) const

MyFunctor x;
type a;
const T& r = x(a); // take reference to const
T c = x(a);        // make copy from reference. Assumes T has copy constructor
T& r = x(a);       // Error! Cannot take reference to non-const!
```

Comment: Can you clarify the differences between the last two?  I'm confused what the const does when it comes after everything.  Also, in the last example, how are we allowed to declare T c = x(a)?  Why doesn't it have to be const T c = x(a)?

Comment: @AshleyPinkman the const after everything means it is a `const` member function, i.e. it cannot modify the instance's data or call any non-const member functions. You are allowed to do this `T c = x(a)` because you are making a *copy*.